# Как возвести в N-ую степень ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

Здравствуйте!

Моя проблема заключается в том, что я не могу возвести в степень элементы `ArrayList`.

Вот как я пытаюсь сделать это:

```
ArrayList<Double> sqrtD = new ArrayList<Double>();
sqrtD.add(1.0);
sqrtD.add(2.0);

for(int i=0;i<sqrtD.size();i++){
    sqrtD.add(Math.pow(sqrtD.get(i), 2));       
}
```

Comment: вы код своих неудачных "попыток" покажите, а то сегодня бури магнитные, экстросенсорно не получается

Comment: @ДмитрийАлександрович вы сделали мой день)))))))))))))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте новый списочный массив, либо сэтом изменяйте существующие. Зачем вы добавляете к имеющимся новые элементы? Или так предусмотрено тз? Например arrList.set(i, Math.pow(arrList.get(i), n));

Answer (score 3):

А можно всё решить довольно просто и в пару строк, используя Java 8 Stream API:

```
List<Double> doubles = Arrays.asList(1.0, 2.0);
doubles = doubles.stream().map(d -> Math.pow(d, 2)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Но стоит заметить, что производительность этого решения существенно ниже.

Comment: Да, прогнал на своем i5 2500K 8GB RAM: на одних и тех же данных `Java 8 Stream API` took: *97491007* nano(s), `Iterator` took: *53493* nano(s)

Comment: @lospejos можно ещё попробовать `parallelStream`, но в целом да, производительность здесь не будет на первом месте :)

Comment: @AlexChermenin в параллель может быть ещё медленнее :)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev может, но в данном случае будет быстрее

Answer (score 2):

Вы добавляете новые элементы в список, а не изменяете существующие. Для того, чтобы изменять итерируюмую коллекцию, стоит воспользоваться итератором:

```
ArrayList<Double> sqrtD = new ArrayList<>();
sqrtD.add(1.0);
sqrtD.add(2.0);

ListIterator<Double> iterator = sqrtD.listIterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    iterator.set(Math.pow(iterator.next(), 2));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<Double> sqrtD = new ArrayList<Double>();
sqrtD.add(1.0);
sqrtD.add(2.0);

for(int i=0;i<sqrtD.size();i++){
    double pow = Math.pow(sqrtD.get(i), 2);
    sqrtD.remove(i);
    sqrtD.add(i, pow);
}
```

Comment: работать будет , однако учитите, что в данном случае фактически не меняется размер коллекции. это важно , потому как в противном случае вы получите исключение